# Is there a way to reduce execution time while reducing batch_size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Here is my code

```
for i in range(10):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(1))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizers.adam())

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=16, verbose=0)

    p = model.predict(x_test)
    mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, p)
    if mse < minval:
        model.save('best.h5')
```

If I increase `batch_size`, MSE goes up as well. Therefore, to reduce MSE, I must reduce `batch_size`.

The problem with increasing `batch_size` is time. As `batch_size` decreases, the execution time increases significantly.

I am wondering how to increase execution speed by reducing `batch_size` without changing hardware.

Or how can I reduce MSE while keeping `batch_size` the same? In this code, `batch_size` has the biggest impact on MSE.

for one´s information, computer resources remain. I want to save time by taking advantage of all the remaining resources, but I'm curious what I can do if I can. (Not half of the GPU memory is used, and the remaining memory is idle. The rest of the resources are the same.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decrease the batch size, then the time is going to increase, and this is basically unavoidable without tuning other parameters.

Please note that while decreasing the batch size to an extent reduce your MSE, reducing it to an absurdly low value is going to raise it, so there's a balance you need to keep.

I do note that you are currently not manually tuning your learning rate, and increasing the learning rate could not only speed up your results but help prevent falling into a local minima. Of course, a learning rate that is also too high might make it less likely for you to reach the global minimum as well.

You can play around with your parameters though overall it's gonna depend on your computer. For example, if you have an i7 instead of an i5, you have hyperthreading which could speed up the process.